# LinkedList implementation in Python not showing beyond the head node

Tags: python, linked-list

My attempts at creating a linked list from scratch in Python are not working, and I'm not sure what I am missing. I tried to create separate classes for nodes and linked lists, but when I am trying to see beyond the head node, I hit a road block.
Appreciate any pointers (no pun intended). Also, what is a better approach: have a separate class for the nodes, or make them an attribute of the linked list class itself?

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
    
    # adding/inserting to the tail
    def add(self, val):
        node_to_add = ListNode()
        if self.head == None:
            self.head = node_to_add
            node_to_add.val = val
        else:
            self.next = node_to_add
            node_to_add.val = val 

    # printing the linked list as a list
    def print(self):
        list_to_print = []
        if not self.head:
            return None
        node_to_read = self.head
        while self.head:
            list_to_print.append(node_to_read.val)
            if node_to_read.next:
                self.head = node_to_read.next
            else:
                return list_to_print
```

When I run this code, I only can print the head node. When I add nodes/values after the first entry, the print() only returns the head.

```
test1 = LinkedList()
test1.add(1)
test1.add(4)
test1.add(7)
test1.print()
```

the output is

```
[1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to append items to the last Node you need to keep track of the last node.

You also should not override your head pointer in the print function.

```py
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    # adding/inserting to the tail
    def add(self, val):
        node_to_add = ListNode()
        node_to_add.val = val
        if self.tail == None:
            self.head = node_to_add
            self.tail = node_to_add
        else:
            self.tail.next = node_to_add
            self.tail = node_to_add


            # printing the linked list as a list

    def print(self):
        list_to_print = []
        if not self.head:
            return None
        current_node = self.head
        while current_node:
            list_to_print.append(current_node.val)
            if current_node.next:
                current_node = current_node.next
            else:
                return list_to_print
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This does it, but I am still trying to wrap my head around the add() where you set both the head and the tail of the list as the new node. The node can't be the current node and the next node, right? I also am trying to understand why there is no need to add the condition where self.head == None which is when the linked list is empty right after we create it. Appreciate any further explanation. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this significantly by giving the node responsibility for adding children. This makes the linked list object basically a wrapper that manages the head and iterations over the list:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
        
    def add(self, node):
        if self.next is None:
            self.next = node
        else:
            self.next.add(node)

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
    
    def add(self, val):
        node = ListNode(val)
        if self.head == None:
            self.head = node
        else:
            self.head.add(node)

    # printing the linked list as a list
    def print(self):
        list_to_print = []
        node_to_read = self.head
        
        while node_to_read:
            list_to_print.append(node_to_read.val)
            node_to_read = node_to_read.next
            
        print(list_to_print)
            
test1 = LinkedList()
test1.add(1)
test1.add(4)
test1.add(7)
test1.print()
# [1, 4, 7]
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This looks cleaner and simpler. I still wish the addition of the nodes was handled by the list. I guess an even simpler approach would be to not have a class Node, and make it an attribute of the LinkedList class

Comment: Most linked lists take the opposite approach. The list class is simply a thin wrapper to keep track of the head. The nodes do all the work. This makes things like splitting a linked list very simple — you just pick a node and call it the head.

Comment: Your add function is recursive. This becomes a problem if you have huge lists.

Comment: @VarChar42 linked lists are recursive data structures. They are primarily used for academic purposes in python to teach recursive structures and functions. This is an appropriate way to do this unless for some reason (which are exceedingly rare) the linked list is used to solve a specific problem. That doesn't seem to be the case here.